# Which one has lower fats? Skim milk Vs. Cottage cheese

Tags: diet, body-fat

I've MS and I would like to ask about which is better to eat Skim milk or cottage cheese?

I especially ask about cottage cheese that is made for generations by our grandmothers at the back of the wood stove on the farm. Can I eat this kind of cheese? Does it contain low fats?

How much should I eat per day to get enough calcium and as low fats as possible? I'm 22 years old male.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer 'better' is mostly subjective. Eating fat does not necessarily make you fat.

Comment: @JJosaur Does cottage chese contain low fats? How much cottage chese should a young, male adult eat to obtain sufficient dietary calcium? Finally, is there a reason for a person with multiple sclerosis not to eat it? I don't see anything subjective about those. The part "which is better" may have been phrased differently to be more suitable for the SE model, but diet in MS is a subject of much debate and these are legitimate questions.